# Upload image as well as change Entity feild in Seam Jboss application

Tags: file, jboss, upload, entity, seam

I have been currently struggling on updating my bean on file upload So here it goes

```
memberEdit.xhtml

<rich:fileUploadfileUploadListener="#{FileUpload.listener}"
              maxFilesQuantity="1" id="upload"  immediateUpload="false"
                acceptedTypes="jpg, gif, png, bmp, jpeg"allowFlash="false">
                <a4j:supportevent="onuploadcomplete"reRender="memberPhotoField"/>
            </rich:fileUpload>

<s:decorateid="memberPhotoField"template="layout/edit.xhtml">
<ui:definename="label">Member photo</ui:define>
<h:inputTextareaid="memberPhoto"cols="80"rows="3"
required="true"value="#{memberHome.instance.memberPhoto}"/>
```

My File upload bean

```
@Name ("FileUpload")
//getters setters
    public void listener(UploadEvent event) throws Exception{
         memberHome memberinstance = new CiomemberHome(); 
        //After copying file on hard disk need to update my text field with filename
         memberinstance.setphoto(item.getFileName());
       // I do get logs correct for item.getFilename
}
```

My Home entity

```
@Name("memberHome")
//getter setters....
public void setphoto(String image)
{
        log.info("In method set photo");
        getInstance().setMemberPhoto(image);
        update(); 
}
```

Comment: Describe your problem better, there's no indication of the problem you experience...

Comment: I am trying to upload image on Hard disk So when my upload completes I want to have file name in one of the text fields so that same page that binds to Entity CIOMEMBER so that when I save my uploaded file name also gets saved in  database.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you **NEVER** want to instantiate Seam components yourself (like in `new CiomemberHome()`), because if you do they are no longer Seam components (bijection will not work, etc.), instead of creating the instances yourself you ask Seam to handle them down with `Component.getInstance("memberHome")` or injecting it in FileUpload.

Regarding your problem, I presume it is that the filename is empty. If this is the problem, then the reason is that richfaces is not actually creating the temporary files but has the content in memory. To store the uploaded data into files, you need to change your `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>createTempFiles</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>maxRequestSize</param-name>
        <param-value>10000000</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Note that `createTempFiles` is set to `true` (the default is false). When retrieving the data in listener, instead of `item.getData()` with a byte array use `File temp = item.getFile()` which returns the temporary file instance.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7276813/1417546

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am not able to rerender my text field with image name. I am able to print on console but on in form.

Answer (score 0):

Errors/Messages

```
13:49:42,540 INFO  [FileUploadBean] result of persist: updated
13:49:42,613 INFO  [lifecycle] WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have       been displayed.
sourceId=null[severity=(INFO 0), summary=(Successfully updated), detail=(Successfully updated)]
sourceId=null[severity=(INFO 0), summary=(Successfully updated), detail=(Successfully updated)]
sourceId=ciomember:officePhoneField:officePhone[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(value is required), detail=(value is required)]
```

sourceId=ciomember:cityField:city[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(value is required), detail=(value    is required)]
   sourceId=ciomember:agencyNameField:agencyName[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(value is required), detail=(value is required)]
    sourceId=ciomember:lastNameField:lastName[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(value is required), detail=(value is required)]
    sourceId=ciomember:memberPhotoField:memberPhoto[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(value is required),    detail=(value is required)]
    sourceId=ciomember:zipField:zip[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(value is required), detail=(value is required)]
    sourceId=ciomember:stateField:state[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(value is required), detail=(value  is required)]
sourceId=ciomember:firstNameField:firstName[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(value is required), detail=(value is required)]
sourceId=ciomember:titleField:title[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(value is required), detail=(value is required)]
sourceId=ciomember:agencyUrlField:agencyUrl[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(value is required), detail=(value is required)]
sourceId=ciomember:address1Field:address1[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(value is required), detail=(value is required)]

Comment: Looks like you have other fields in the form together with the `rich:fileUpload` control. When you submit the file, you also submit the entire form and the required fields do not pass validation, that's the reason for the errors you see. Try using `ajaxSingle=true` in the `rich:fileUpload` control or put it in a separate form so that it is submitted separately and does not require validation of the other fields.

Comment: Thank you so much but why do I have sourceId=null[severity=(INFO 0), summary=(Successfully updated), detail=(Successfully updated)]
sourceId=null[severity=(INFO 0), summary=(Successfully updated), detail=(Successfully updated)]

Comment: Why my sourceId is null why? Though I am grabbing my Instance.

Comment: `sourceId=null` does not imply a problem, it just means that the message is not attached to any JSF control (a global message). You see this warning because you're not re-rendering the faces messages display tag (`<h:messages/>`). To avoid the warn in the log and display the faces message, assign an id to the div with the messages tag and add it to the `reRender` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for trying on my issue. But I figured it out I needed to have @Inject on that modal entity so that I can use the current Instance and manipulate it. Thank you. :)